# Googlebot mobile, What's wrong in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive, googlebot

This code (detect mobile device and redirect to the optimized style)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = window.location.href + "?style=Mobile";
    }
</script>
```

Works perfectly in all my mobiles and also to the users of the website, but, when I went to test it on GoogleBot Mobile:
https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly

I receive this alert-message: "Wow! An error has occurred,
Wait a bit and try again"

Looks like this bot can't access to the url-site... Someone knows why?

EDIT:

I think it could be related with `window.location.href` because if I use specific URL the test works well, but I need that detect the current url of the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will loop.

Try this

```
var srch = window.location.search;
if (srch.indexOf("=Mobile") == -1) window.location = window.location.href + "?style=Mobile";
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I recived the same error message from Googlebot Mobile Friendly test :( for other hand your code also works on my mobile :) I don't know why Google can't access there...